# How can I make the queryset filter `or` conditions dynamically from the array?

Tags: python, django, filter

I have `array` and try to use this as filter key for database

I want to make this dynamically from the `array = [AC" ,"BC"]`

```
 queryset = queryset.filter(Q(username__icontains="AC")| Q(username__icontains="BC"))
```

For example, I try like this below but it is obviously wrong.

```
array = ["AC","BC"]
qs = []
for k in array:
   qs.append(Q(username__icontains=k))
   
queryset = queryset.filter(qs.join('|'))
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Q Django's class you might use |= operator to build your query dynamically with OR logic

```
query = Q()

for el in array:
    query |= Q(username__icontains=el)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use reduce to achieve such a thing, like:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
final_condition = reduce(or_, conditions_list) # this will be your condition
```

Comment: I tried this but still reduce is a bit too difficult for me... but thank you very much! I ned to learn more